# Trying to send a PHP form from Android Studio

Tags: php, android-studio, psql

Okay, so I'm very new at programming for android studio and I have a pretty basic question.

I've looked around and found various answers and haven't been able to understand very many of them. Many have the HttpClient solution, but that doesn't seem to work since it's been removed since Android 23(?).

Basically I've setup a PHP file on a hosted server and I can send information through a php command or just through the browser using something like

example.edu/~example/php/test.php?argument1=xxx

I'm trying to execute this through android studio and have no idea how to proceed.

Basically what I want it to do is, On button click, send the information.

This is what I have so far but it doesnt seem to work.

```
link = "https://xxx.edu/~yyy/php/test.php?argument1=xz&argument2="+first+"&argument3="+last+"&argument4="+ageins;
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(link);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Edit: I am only sending information, there is no return value on the PHP as of now. Basically all the stuff I'm sending is populating a psql database on the server.

Comment: Going to need a lot more information to help you on this question. What doesn't seem to work. Where does it fail. Are you getting any errors in your java code? Are you receiving the data in PHP? Can you log the data you get server side?

Comment: @OleHaugset So I'm not sure if the server's even receiving the message from the application. I am not a sudo user of the server, so no, there's no way for me to check. I've already emailed the server admin to see if there's any logs of information received. I think there's no communication from the phone to the server. I wasn't getting any errors on studio, but when I edited some code, the app just crashed on button press.

Comment: Well, then its hard for us to debug it for your. sorry. I'm a PHP programmer, so I cant tell you if your Java code is wrong or correct, but on this little information, theres really nothing to work from.